# Stud wall that doesn't connect to ceiling?

Tags: bathroom, walls, framing

I am going to be framing out a stud wall in a bathroom for a new walk-in shower. The room has tall vaulted ceilings and I do not want this new shower wall to go all the way up. Maybe just 7-8 feet tall or so with a finished top.

Is it ok for me to frame a wall that doesn't go all the way to the ceiling?
I expect so, but how should I connect to floor and wall to ensure it is as sturdy as possible, given it will not have support from above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  I wanted my pony wall very stiff, so I ran a 2-inch pipe from the top plate to some blocking at the bottom of the joists below the subfloor.  You might get away with screwing the bottom plate to the josts and using a bracket designed for preventing the studs from prying away from the bottom plate.  Also, you might consider a 2x6 wall instead of 2x4.

[Here is a nice rundown of the options.](http://www.aconcordcarpenter.com/reinforcing-a-pony-wall.html)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! And great link. You also taught me this was called a "pony wall" :)